# build bsdiff into static link .a

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, configure, autotools, bsdiff

I would like to use [bsdiff](https://github.com/mendsley/bsdiff) into c++ project by external links.

So I have to build a static link. I can do that with `ar rcs bsdiff.a bsdiff.o`
But there is already a main function. So When I link bsdiff.a to my cpp build and build it, I have `redefinition of main function`.

So how avoid the main function ?

(I already try to comment `bsdiff_CFLAGS = -DBSDIFF_EXECUTABLE` into `Makefile.am` but get `undefined reference to main function`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build system provided with the project is quite simple and does not support building the code as a library. As per [documentation](https://github.com/mendsley/bsdiff#overview):

> The easiest way to integrate is to simply copy the c file to your source folder and build it.

I would not call project's build system, but rather compile required files directly as part of your project, as developer suggests.